# Users with Design Rights not able to edit default aspx

Tags: 2007

Afternoon all,

I have a scenario where some of my users, who have both Contribute and Design rights within a site are unable to edit the default.aspx homepage.  They're not seeing the "Modify Shared Web Part" section on any of the CEWPs, yet they're able to edit site settings and the myriad of settings there.  The user can also access the Web Part Addition field via direct linking (default.aspx?ToolPaneView2.aspx)

1. The site isn't a publishing site and doesn't have approval on it
2. The "Edit Shared Web par" still doesn't appear when attempted via the ?ToolPaneView2.aspx page
3. The permission groups for the Designer User Member group are permissioned accordingly

For informative purposes, our farm is a SharePoint 2007 (Standard) farm.  I've yet to do any testing with compatability mode.

Any ideas / suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, worked this out.  It was indeed compatability mode.  Turned this on for the end users and the expected opions appeared.

For the sake of clarity and any one reading this post in the future, we were using IE9